# Accidentally mentioned the names of shortlist candidates for a job

Tags: interviewing, job-change

I recently vacated a job to take a different one in the same organization.

My previous employer asked me to help in the process of replacing me in that position.  In the process, she asked me about the three candidates that she was considering, and wanted any information that I thought might be helpful.

Well, recently I was in a conversation with another person in our organization about my old job, and this person knew of one of the candidates and his status as a possible hire.  During the conversation, I accidentally mentioned the names of the other two, BOTH of which he knew.  I felt awful and a tiny bit panicky afterwards.  He didn't seem surprised by either of them, and acted as though he probably would have found out eventually anyway.

So the question is, how much damage could I have done, and what could I do at this point, if anything, to mitigate that damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every organization is different, so there's really no way someone on an online Q&A site can tell you what damage would be done.  As an insider with the organization, you are in a better position to know what that would be.  It could be nothing, or you could have jeopardized the chances of one or more candidates.

To mitigate any chance of damage, it would be good for you to go back to this other person and explain that you shouldn't have divulged the names of the other two candidates and ask them to keep the names a secret.  Also, you could go to those making the decision about which candidate gets the position, explain that you inadvertently divulged who the candidates are, just so they know how the names may have gotten out.

All that said I would hope that your statements would not affect decisions about the candidates, since they cannot control you.

Comment: >.. keep the names a secret. You know what happens when you ask someone to keep a secret, yea ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already left the job with your previous employer the more damage can occur to your previous employer if any. The below points to help you to mitigate the damage

**1. Check that Are you supposed to maintain confidential?**
Check with the policies and other rules of the previous organization or team which says that you need to make it confidential. And also it is good to check with previous employer about confidentiality of this matter. If you are not expected or supposed to make it confidential the damage and impact is less. The below points(2 & 3) are optional for you. If you are expected to make it confidential you have to follow points 2& 3 which are specified below.

**2. Talk with the Person to whom you have revealed the Names**
Have a conversation with the person to whom you have revealed names. Tell him that It is a confidential matter and you are revealed him since you are trusting him much and request him don't reveal any one.

**3. Talk with your previous Employer**
Bring this matter to your previous employer and apologize for causing this problem. And give the full details of incident. He/She will take care of controlling damage and also if they requested any thing to control the damage. And provide your full help and support to control the damage if any.